# How to open up text editor (edit or fix) in R Shiny?

Tags: r, editor, shiny, text-editor

I'm trying to allow the user of the shiny app to edit a dataset through a text editor, similar to what can be achieved with `edit()` or `fix()`.

Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
  dataset <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    dataset$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })

  example <- eventReactive(input$actionbutton, {
    resultobject <- dataset$data
    fix(resultobject)
    }
    return(resultobject)
  })
```

However, nothing shows up when the actionbutton is clicked. So my question is: first, is this possible to do in shiny, and if so, where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe look into shinysky package and its hotable?